Should we suppress negative thought or not?
We are told one should not suppress negative thoughts. But a 2023 research by Cambridge says that it is beneficial to suppress negative thoughts (https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/suppressing-negative-thoughts-good-for-mental-health). Why the discrepancies? Should we suppress negative thoughts or not?

Related: Does suppressing a desire make it more powerful?

“Why the discrepancies?” Because it was a poorly designed study. “Should we suppress negative thoughts?” No.
